# Cambiar dinámicamente valores de un diccionario incluido dentro de una lista

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
sample = [{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.0} for _ in range(100)]
for mu in range(len(sample)):
    print sample[mu]['b']
    print sample[mu]['x']
```

Ahora imaginemos que deseo cambiar los valores del diccionario dependiendo del valor de otra variable denominada `players = [1,2,3,4]`, de tal manera que `for player in players:` pueda redefinir los valores de `'b'` y `'x'` en el diccionario de manera dinámica.
Por ejemplo:

```
if player == 1: 
    que 'b' tome el valor 0.1 y 'x'tome 0.4
if player == 2: 
    que 'b' tome el valor 0.2 y 'x'tome 0.5
if player == 3: 
    que 'b' tome el valor 0.3 y 'x'tome 0.6
if player == 4: 
    que 'b' tome el valor 0.4 y 'x'tome 0.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al principio, para definir la lista inicial puedes usar un objeto `defaultdict` el cual inicializa todos los elementos de un diccionario automáticamente, de la siguiente manera:

```
import collections as co

sample = [co.defaultdict(int) for _ in range(100)]
```

Para la segunda parte puedes crear un diccionario aparte con los valores que deseas para `b` y `x` dependiendo del valor de `player`:

```
valores_player = {players[0]: {'b': 0.1, 'x': 0.4}, players[1]: {'b': 0.2, 'x': 0.5}, players[2]: {'b': 0.3, 'x': 0.6}, players[3]: {'b': 0.4, 'x': 0.7}}
```

Los valores se asignarían de la siguiente manera:

```
sample[0] = valores_player[player]
```

o si deseas mantener el `defaultdict` en cada elemento de `sample`

```
sample[0]['b'] = valores_player[player]['b']
sample[0]['x'] = valores_player[player]['x']
```

Si los valores `player` empezasen en `0` podrías crear `valores_player` como una lista de diccionarios en lugar de un diccionario de diccionarios:

```
valores_player = [{'b': 0.1, 'x': 0.4}, {'b': 0.2, 'x': 0.5}, {'b': 0.3, 'x': 0.6}, {'b': 0.4, 'x': 0.7}]
```

Todo lo anterior es partiendo del hecho que los valores a asignar a `b` y `x` a partir del valor de `player` no tengan relación. Si los valores en cambio sí tienen relación como en el ejemplo (`b` y `x` son incrementos de `0.1`), podrías crear `valores_player` de la siguiente manera:

```
players = [1, 2, 3, 4]
valores_player = {vp: {'b': 0.1 + (vp - 1) * 0.1, `x`: 0.4 + (vp - 1) * 0.1} for vp in players}
```

Si en este último caso `players` tiene valores distintos a `[1, 2, 3, 4]` (como cadenas o enteros no consecutivos), podrías alcanzar la misma solución haciéndola independiente de los valores de `players`. Quedaría así:

```
players = ["uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"]
valores_player = {players[i]: {'b': 0.1 + i * 0.1, `x`: 0.4 + i * 0.1} for i in range(len(players))}
```

Comment: Hola Carlos. Muchas gracias por la respuesta aunque me temo que no consigo resolver mi problema. En verdad para lo que quiero el código es para invocar los diferentes valores de 'b' y 'x' (según cada player) utilizando una sola línea. El código lo quiero integrar dentro de un programa más complejo que tengo. Si tienes tiempo y ganas podemos abrir un chat y compartiendo el código a lo mejor ves mi problema mejor. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: @pyring Aunque si quieres obtener los distintos valores de `'b'` y `'x'` según cada `player`, con el código que te he puesto lo puedes hacer: `valores_player[player]['b']` o `valores_player[player]['x']` para acceder a los valores de `'b'`y `'x'` respectivamente para `player`.

Comment: sí no tengo problema para acceder los valores de 'b' y 'x', el problema lo tengo al intentar invocarlos con mi código, que funciona con clases y es un poco más complejo. Creo que no tengo credenciales aún para invitar a un chat, por lo que si a ti no te importa y tienes tiempo libre, encantado si procedes tú mismo a initarme!

Comment: @pyring ¿Cómo se crea un chat? No tengo ni idea.